# Get value of two columns when pivoting

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has entries like

```
Acct    Nurse   EntryDateTime          DBCode   Answer  FormSeq
123     Sally     9/8/2020 09:22        Code1    Ans1     0001
123     Jim     9/8/2020 10:25          Code1    Ans2     0001
123     Sally    9/8/2020  09:15        Code2    C2Ans1   0001
```

I have a query that is pivoting this to get the answer from the last entry based on DBCode and EntryDateTime that works great. What  I need to do is get the NURSE as well as the answer.

So my row would be

```
Acct   Code1    Code1Nurse     Code2      Code2Nurse
123    Ans2       Jim            C2Ans1   Sally
```

Is there a way to do this? I would need the nurse for each unique DBCode

Here is my pivot code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [AcctNumber],
    [Answer],
   
    [DBCode],
    [EntryDate],
    [FormCode],[FormSeq]
   
  FROM V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY
) MultiApp
PIVOT (
 MAX( [Answer])
  FOR [DBCode]
  IN (
    [AST],
    [SDRM],
    [SDRF],[SDAAS],[SDDCT],[SDDAS],[SDABY],[SDDAT],[SDTRCC],[SDADMTW],[Prptic],[Pdcrt]
  )
) AS PivotTable WHERE EntryDate >='8/15/2020' and FormCode='LL003' ORDER BY EntryDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation.

Data

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
(123, 'Sally', '9/8/2020 09:22', 'Code1', 'Ans1', '0001'),
(123, 'Jim', '9/8/2020 10:25', 'Code1', 'Ans2', '0001'),
(123, 'Sally', '9/8/2020  09:15', 'Code2', 'C2Ans1', '0001')) V(Acct, Nurse, EntryDateTime, DBCode, Answer, FormSeq);
```

Query

```
;with rn_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by DBCode order by EntryDateTime desc) rn
    from #tTEST)
select Acct, 
      max(case when DBCode='Code1' and rn=1 then Answer else null end) Code1,
      max(case when DBCode='Code1' and rn=1 then Nurse else null end) Code1Nurse,
      max(case when DBCode='Code2' and rn=1 then Answer else null end) Code2,
      max(case when DBCode='Code2' and rn=1 then Nurse else null end) Code2Nurse
from rn_cte
group by Acct;
```

Output

```
Acct    Code1   Code1Nurse  Code2   Code2Nurse
123     Ans2    Jim         C2Ans1  Sally
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to play with. It would take some tinkering, but you could make the query dynamic to build out the columns to select based upon the DBCodes you have in your table...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY;

CREATE TABLE #V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY 
    (
        Acct INT,    
        Nurse VARCHAR(20),
        EntryDateTime DATETIME,
        DBCode VARCHAR(10),
        Answer VARCHAR(10),
        FormSeq VARCHAR(10)
    )
INSERT  #V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY
VALUES
    (123,'Sally','9/8/2020 09:22','Code1','Ans1','0001'),
    (123,'Jim','9/8/2020 10:25','Code1','Ans2','0001'),
    (123,'Sally','9/8/2020 09:15','Code2','C2Ans1','0001');


WITH    Top_Row_Per_DBCode_By_EntryDate AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DBCode ORDER BY EntryDateTime DESC) AS top_row,
            Acct,
            DBCode,
            Nurse+':'+Answer AS Answer
    FROM    #V_FAC_MULTIAPP_FORM_WITH_HOURLY
),  Filtered_CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Top_Row_Per_DBCode_By_EntryDate
    WHERE   top_row = 1
)
SELECT  Acct, 
        Substring([Code1],CHARINDEX(':',[Code1])+1,LEN([Code1])-CHARINDEX(':',[Code1])) AS Code1,
        Substring([Code1],0,CHARINDEX(':',[Code1])) AS Code1Nurse, 
        Substring([Code2],CHARINDEX(':',[Code2])+1,LEN([Code2])-CHARINDEX(':',[Code2])) AS Code2,
        Substring([Code2],0,CHARINDEX(':',[Code2])) AS Code2Nurse
FROM    Filtered_CTE
PIVOT
(
    MAX( [Answer]) FOR [DBCode]
    IN ([Code1],[Code2])
) AS PivotTable
```